# Limit of logarithm

Tags: limits, logarithms

I came across this relation a lot,when evaluating lim of function like natural logarithm I could find that evaluating limit for logarithm equal to evaluating logarithm for limit. Why this is true?
$$\lim \ln(f(x))=\ln \lim f(x)$$

Comment: Because $\ln$ is a continuous function. In a sense, that is the definition of continuity: limits commute with the evaluation of the function. (The "function" being $\ln$, not $f$.)

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: why do we need uniform continuity? Taking limits is a local behavior and continuity is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

This property is continuity, and it's known that the natural logarithm is continuous on its domain.

Put more generally, if $ \lim_{x \to a} g(x) = b $ and if $ f $ is continuous at $ b $, then $ \lim_{x \to a} f(g(x)) = f(\lim_{x \to a} g(x)) $. The natural logarithm is continuous at every point in its domain, so "commuting" the limit with the log is valid.

Answer (score 0):

It follows directly from continuity, as suggested by all other comments. Indeed, if we denote $f_0(x) := \lim(f(x))$, for any $\varepsilon >0$,

$$ \| \ln(f(x)) - \ln(f_0(x)) \| < \varepsilon $$

holds for some $\delta > 0$ such that $ \| f(x) - f_0(x) \| < \delta $. And the latter is implied when $f$ converges to $f_0$.